# Maven Cucumber throwing Exception

Tags: java, maven

I am trying to compile a test file and following is the command.

> mvn clean integration-test
>   -Djob.allowed.max.runtime.in.ms=3600000 -Dcucumber.options="--tags @Task" -Djob.host.name=server-name
>   -Dsurefire.report.location="target/result1"

But this seems to be throwing this Exception

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "3600000 -Dcucumber.options=--tags @Task"
```

Does anyone know about it ?

Comment: Looks like the command you pasted and the one you actually run are not the same

Comment: No its the same, May I know why do you say so ?

Comment: Because of the error: the argument to `job.allowed.max.runtime.in.ms` is `36000000 -D...`. The command as you have pasted it does not have this problem.